# Spring MVC Controller mapping does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, web-applications

I am working on a spring-mvc project. After many tries, I am unable to the map the controller in spring. As a result, the below url always returns as 404 not found.

http://localhost:8080/EcommerceBookStore/rest/welcome

Here is the web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>EcommerceBookStore</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>
  
    <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,
                /WEB-INF/Ecommerce-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
    </context-param>
    
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Ecommerce</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Ecommerce</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
   
   

  
<!--  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Ecommerce</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.java.Client</param-name>
        <param-value>com.java.Client</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
     <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
     <param-value>true</param-value>
   </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>-->
  
  
</web-app>
```

Here is the Ecommerce-servlet.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

 
 
 <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
 
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:argument-resolvers>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.bind.support.AuthenticationPrincipalArgumentResolver" />
        </mvc:argument-resolvers>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <!-- bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WebContent" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean-->
 <bean id="viewResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass"
   value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.webspider"/>
 
    <mvc:resources mapping="/Resources/**" location="/Resources/" />
   

</beans>
```

Here is the

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:webflow-config="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config.xsd">

 <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
  id="dataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Ecommerce"></property>
  <property name="username" value="root"></property>
  <property name="password" value="pass"></property>
 </bean>
 
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties" >
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.webspider</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10240000" />
    </bean>

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/customer/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:form-login
            login-page="/login"
            default-target-url="/product/productList"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <security:logout
            logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:jdbc-user-service
                    data-source-ref="dataSource"
                    authorities-by-username-query="SELECT username, authority FROM authorities WHERE username = ?"
                    users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password, enabled FROM users WHERE username = ?" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <webflow-config:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry" />
    
    <webflow-config:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows">
        <webflow-config:flow-location path="/checkout/checkout-flow.xml" id="checkout" />
    </webflow-config:flow-registry>

    <bean id="flowHandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
        <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="flowHandlerAdapter" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here is the helloworld controller

```
    package com.webspider.Controller;


    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

   /*
    * author: Crunchify.com
    * 
    */

@Controller
public class HelloWorld {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "<br><div style='text-align:center;'>"
                + "<h3>********** Hello World, Spring MVC Tutorial</h3>This message is coming from CrunchifyHelloWorld.java **********</div><br><br>";
        return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message);
    }
}
```

Here is the tomcat output

```html
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/atishpatra/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:15 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:15 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:15 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 972 ms
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.38
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:18 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'Ecommerce'
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:18 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'Ecommerce': initialization started
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:18 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'Ecommerce-servlet': startup date [Wed Nov 23 00:41:18 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:18 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/Ecommerce-servlet.xml]
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:19 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition
INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:19 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition
INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:19 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition
INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean 'mvcUriComponentsContributor' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [org.springframework.web.servlet.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser$CompositeUriComponentsContributorFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null] with [Root bean: class [org.springframework.web.servlet.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser$CompositeUriComponentsContributorFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:19 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler#0'
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:20 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'Ecommerce-servlet': startup date [Wed Nov 23 00:41:18 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:20 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'Ecommerce-servlet': startup date [Wed Nov 23 00:41:18 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:20 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/Resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:20 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'Ecommerce': initialization completed in 2089 ms
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:21 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:21 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Nov 23, 2016 12:41:21 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 5855 ms
```

I dont see any error in tomcat output. I expected something similar to appear

INFO: Mapped URL path [/welcome] onto handler HelloWorld.

I have no clue what's wrong. Can anyone please point out what I am missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `http://localhost:8080/rest/welcome`? Did you look in Tomcat's management webapp to see what URLs are mapped?

Comment: What is your project name in tomcat under webapps folder ?

Comment: Have you considered using Spring Boot, which will eliminate about 90% of that?

Comment: I have tried http://localhost:8080/rest/welcome . Same 404 not found

Comment: How do I access Tomcat's management webapp ?
http://localhost:8080/manager/html - does not work

Comment: I think you are missing some configuration. Add <context:annotation-config> tag in spring conf xml.Also add init param tag for in web xml for servlet and try once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have mixed here:

If your project name is rest and you are deploying it as rest.war then you don't need this line in web.xml

```
<url-pattern>/rest/</url-pattern>
```

change it to

```
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

but if you are running it with ROOT.war and you want /rest in url then you have to do as below:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class HelloWorld {
```

and then access with below url:
localhost:8080//rest/welcome

Comment: Project name is EcommerceBookStore.

Comment: Project name means when you build your project what is war file name?

Comment: war file name is EcommerceBookStore.

After I removed /rest from url-pattern and executed following url

http://localhost:8080/EcommerceBookStore/welcome

I am getting following error in tomcat log.


org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/EcommerceBookStore/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'Ecommerce

Comment: look, if your war file name is EcommerceBookStore.war then put /EcommerceBookStore after localhost:8080 and if your war file name is rest.war then put /rest after localhost:8080 and if your war filename is ROOT.war then don't put anything after localhost:8080.

Comment: Please ignore about /rest. I have removed that after your comment for trying.


My war filename is EcommerceBookStore.war. That's why I am executing the following url


localhost:8080/EcommerceBookStore/welcome

And getting below error in tomcat



**org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI **



**[/EcommerceBookStore/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'Ecommerce**


Any hints ?

Comment: Okay. Now change <context:component-scan base-package="com.webspider"/> to <context:component-scan base-package="com.webspider.*"/> or <context:component-scan base-package="com.webspider.controller"/> and then restart server after uploading new war

Comment: @Naman this is not required. All subpackages will be scanned automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
@RequestMapping("/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView helloWorld() {...
```

Make sure your mapping is,

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Ecommerce</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Customize your default servlet name as,

```
 <mvc:default-servlet-handler default-servlet-name="Ecommerce"/>
```

URL to try : localhost:8080/Ecommerce/welcome